Finding posterior of M/N given posterior of M. (Gamma Distribution)
I'm trying to solve a question about posterior distribution of Gamma scalar multiplication/division. I will give some context to the question here:
$Y_1,..., Y_n$ is modelled as IID Pois($\mu$) random variables, with $\mu=N\pi$. ($N$ is the set of values that each $Y_i$ can take $\{0,...,N\}$). Let $M$ be the (Bayesian) random version of $\mu$, so that $M=N\Pi$. A sensible prior for $M$ is $Gamma(\nu, \lambda)$. Show that under this prior, the posterior distribution is $Gamma(\nu+n\bar{y}, \lambda + n)$.
I was able to prove that using Bayes rule (posterior is proportional to prior times likelihood. I used the poisson likelihood for the Y variables)
The next part of the question asks to show that the posterior distribution of $\frac{M}{N}|y_1,...,y_n$ is $Gamma(\nu + n\bar{y}, N(\lambda+n))$.
I tried using the identity $cX \sim Gamma(\nu, c\lambda)$, however this led me to get $\frac{M}{N}|y_1,...,y_n \sim Gamma(\nu + n\bar{y}, \frac{\lambda+n}{N})$. What approach am I supposed to take here?

Poisson distributions do not have an upper limit on the values they can take, so I am not clear what $N$ or $\pi$ or $\Pi$ represent.  $N$ seems essential to the question.
